# mysql: finding groups of records within a specified time period in Java

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I want to link the mysql database using Java, execute query returns the record of the specified period, and finally present the result in form of table in java.
How can I convert the input string into the mysql valid date and output the result?
I tried this, but failed.

```
Connection con = DBCon.dbcon();
java.util.Date t1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(jTextField2.getText());
java.util.Date t2= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(jTextField3.getText());

PreparedStatement query = con.prepareStatement(SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE TransactionDate >= ？ and TransactionDate <=  '"+t1+"' and id1=?);

ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
```

Thank you very much!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set parameters to `PreparedStatement` instance as follows:

```
Connection con = DBCon.dbcon();
java.util.Date t1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(jTextField2.getText());
java.util.Date t2= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(jTextField3.getText());

PreparedStatement query = con.prepareStatement(SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE TransactionDate >= ? AND TransactionDate <= ? AND id1 = ?);
query.setDate(1,new java.sql.Date(t1.getTime()));
query.setDate(2,new java.sql.Date(t2.getTime()));
query.setLong(3,id);// Assuming Datatype of Id to Long and value in variable id, Change accordingly if not.

ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
```

**Edit :** Changed datatype of setDate from `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date`

Comment: query.setDate(1,t1); query.setDate(2,t2)  I am afraid this is not right,in table transaction datetime is 2th colunm,I want records which time from t1 to t2

Comment: There are three parameters in the Query  SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE TransactionDate >= ? AND TransactionDate <= ? AND id1 = ?. represented by ? respectively and values have to be set in same order. It is independent of column in the table

Comment: it's  my mistake.  but  there has problem in" query.setDate(1,t1)"  it says t1 is not date type.

Comment: Date passed in setDate() should be instant of java.sql.Date, you have to change the data type of t1 and t2 from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date

Comment: You may want to pass new java.sql.Date(t1.getTime()) and new java.sql.Date(t2.getTime()) at index 1 and 2 respectively.